# Importing MakeHuman assets into Blender

Tags: scripting, add-on, makehuman

I created a character (human model) in [MakeHuman](http://www.makehuman.org/index.php) and would like to import it into Blender, make some additional modifications to it, and then save it as a blend (`.blend` file).

I would think that a super popular open source character editor like MakeHuman would make it *really* easy to accomplish this. But they don't have any documentation on their site for how to do this, and after searching online all I could find was [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bCiIVIB673k&t=611s) which makes the process seem super complicated, unsupported and failure prone:

1. Download an old (2014) plugin for MakeHuman and install it (**its no longer supported and may very well not work with modern versions of Blender**)
2. Download BlenderTools from MakeHuman and install them in Blender's `scripts/` directory
3. Restart Blender, then activate the MakeHuman Add-Ons from inside Blender

This seems really brittle and wonky to me. Has anybody ever got this working before? **Is there a better/easier way to import MakeHuman assets into Blender?**

Comment: Export the model as an .obj and rig with rigify if you don't want to mess with mhx2. Textures chosen in MH will be in makehuman exports directory.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @Timaroberts (+1) - when I go to Export and select "*Wavefront obj*" as the Mesh format, the only option for Rig format is "*Biovision Hierarchy BVH*". Is that OK to use or am I looking in the wrong place?!? Thanks again!!

Comment: ^^^And for what its worth I *had* gone to Skeleton >> Game Engine (rig preset), which I **believe** "rigs" the model, but am fine if I have to lose MakeHuman's rig data and rig it inside of Blender instead. But of course, if I can keep this rig data in MakeHuman and export it into Blender, that saves me the trouble of rigging in Blender.

Comment: Exporting as .obj will not get you a rigged mesh as far as I know, so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022 there seems to be a better way:

In order to do direct imports from MakeHuman, you must enable the “socket server” inside MakeHuman. This is disabled per default.

In MakeHuman, load your model and find the **Community** > **Socket** tab. Check the **Accept connections** checkbox. The center column should indicate that the server socket is started.

[image]

- in Blender 3.0.0 or newer, download and install the [MPFB2 plugin for Blender](https://download.tuxfamily.org/makehuman/plugins/mpfb2-latest.zip)
- once installed you can use the tab "MPFB" in the <kbd>N</kbd> side shelf. There are many options, you can use the **Import human** button to import with default settings or customise it.

[image]

You can even create a new human from scratch inside Blender, there are more instructions in the [MakeHuman Community guide](http://static.makehumancommunity.org/mpfb/docs/getting_started.html).

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answer by @Luciano... If you have MakeHuman and blender with MPFB2 on the same machine, you should be able to simply open the MHM file (ie the save file from MakeHuman) directly from MPFB:

[image]

For more information on MPFB2, see http://static.makehumancommunity.org/mpfb.html